# Magento SalesOrderList... is there a ligth weight version of this, or a way to trim down the returned value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, magento, soap

I am attempting to get all the orders from a magento instance.  Once a day we grab all the orders..  (sometimes a few thousand)

*Extra stuff that's more why I ask:*

*I'm using ruby-on-rails to grab the orders. This involves sending the soap call to the magento instance.  It's easy as.

Once I have the response, I convert it into a Hash (a tree) and then pick out the increment id's of the orders and proceed to call getOrder with the increment id.*

I have two problems with what's going on now,  one operational, and one religious. 
Grabbing the XML response to the list request takes really really long and when you tack on the work involved in converting the XML to a hash, I'm seeing a really slow processes.
The religious bit is that I just want the increment_ids so why do I have to pay for the processing/bandwidth to support a hugely bloated response.

Ok  so the question...
Is there a way to set the response returned from Magento, to include only specific fields?  Only the updated_at and the increment_id  for instance. 
If not, is there another call I'm not aware of, that can get just the increment_ids and date?

---

Edit
Below is an example of what I'm looking for from magento but it's for ebay.  I send this xml up to ebay, and get back a really really specific bit of info about the product.   It works for orders and such too.  I can say "only this" and get just that.  I want the same from **Magento**

```
<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<SKU>b123-332</SKU><OutputSelector>ItemId</OutputSelector>          
</GetItemRequest>
```

Comment: You ask for a lot here :) - if you can setup a little module with a controller you can do something like this: http://pastebin.com/dg36cs4m

Comment: Actually I just want a small thing.. an xml (soap) string that I could send to get a smaller xml returned.  Totally language agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a rubygem that gives you your salesOrderList response in the form of a hash, and you can do what you want with the orders after you've received them back (i.e. select the fields you want including increment_id). Just run

```
gem install magento_api_wrapper
```

To do what you want to do, you would do something like this:

```
api = MagentoApiWrapper::Sales.new(magento_url: "yourmagentostore.com/index.php", magento_username: "soap_api_username", magento_api_key: "userkey123")

orders = api.order_list(simple_filters: [{key: "status" value: "complete"}])

orders.map {|o| [o.increment_id, o.items.first.sku] }
```

Rough guess, but you get the idea. You would get the array of hashes back and you can do what you want with them after that. Good luck!

Comment: To keep the site current, we are requested to post the important information from a site instead of just sharing a link. This helps the site be useful even after other sites go down.

Comment: Thom, I edited to remove the link, I assume that's what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes. Links are fine to have and you don't need to remove it. It's simply the SO way to copy the germane parts into the answer so that it can be useful after the link is gone.